# selecting input for test by name. React-testing-library and Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Is there any way I can select this Formik `Field` `<input/>` in react-testing-library

```
            <Field
              style={inputStyles}
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
              placeholder="Name"
              name='name'
              value={values.name}
              className={errors.name && touched.name ? `${newUserFormStyles.errorOutline} ${newUserFormStyles.input}` : newUserFormStyles.input}
            />
```

**my Test**

```
  test('yayayaya', () => {

    const { getByRole } = render(<AddUserForm />);

    const inputName = getByRole('textbox', { name: /name/i })
    const inputName = screen.getByRole('input', { name: 'name' })

    console.log(inputName)

  })
```

neither of the two variables above is successfully grabbing the input field.

Comment: Can we see how the DOM looks? `screen.debug(null, 5000)` and look for the input you try to target, there is a few chances.

a) input its not type text b) input have no aria-label

Comment: What do you get from `screen.getByLabelText(/name/i)` ? does that work?, see https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-formik/ weird the official example use getByLabelText instead of getByRole, maybe a Formik thing?